# How to match multiple lines before certain words

Tags: regex, perl

I want to extract the dialogues made only by "FOO BAR" in some meeting transcripts.

The dialogue sometimes spreads to multiple lines, and I don't know how to extract multiple lines of text.

I thought it could be related to the use of range operator with upper case letters and colon for people's name, but I could not figure out this by myself.

```
my $word = 'FOO BAR';

while (<DATA>) {
    print if /\b$word\b/i .. /[A-Z]:/
}


__DATA__
FOO BAR: Good morning. 
I want to meet you later.
JONE DOE: Good morning
FOO BAR: Thank you.
See you later.
JANE DOE: Thank you.
See you later.
```

#### output

```
FOO BAR: Good morning. 
FOO BAR: Thank you.
```

Comment: Okay. So what is wrong with what you have written?

Comment: A file like that is impossible to parse unless *either* you insist that no one may use a colon when transcribing comments, or you provide a list of contributors whose tags may appear before a comment in the transcript.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't have a solution unless the data is much more restricted.

Comment: I agree with objections by @Borodin.  I would suggest that the OP adds more specific conditions.  For example, that there can be no text, other than the qualifying names, that is _two words in block capitals followed by the colon_.  Or some such.

Comment: @zdim: I don't think that's useful. The input is likely to be manually-entered and so there may well be mistakes as well as non-capital letters before each colon. This question is a lot more than the usual *pls write me a regex* trash.

Comment: @Borodin  Well, I agree -- but as such it is a good problem.  Also, it is a real problem which needs solving.  Perhaps the asker can specify it further.  Your idea of providing the list of participants is very reasonable and seems feasible.  It's not hunders of people.

Comment: @ykjang I have removed my answer for now, since at this point I believe that your question needs more specific conditions. The question is fine, it is just that the problem itself is hard. See the comments for suggestions.

Comment: @zdim: I'm not sure what you mean by *"a good problem"*. The OP's first approach must be to put in procedural restrictions so that the transcription may be parsed. It is not something that can be solved by software.

Comment: @Borodin I mean a realistic and rounded problem.  Once such restrcitions are put in place and stated as requirements the software for it can be written.  I think that it would then make for a very useful page on SO. It would also inform that a problem like this _needs_ those specifics.

Comment: @zdim: Maybe, but the real solution has to be in the data entry code, which is currently probably Notepad or Word.

Answer (score 1):

Set a flag. Turn it on when you find the name you're looking for. Turn it off when you find a different name. Only print when the flag is on.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $word = 'FOO BAR';
my $spew;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^([A-Z ]+):/) {
        $spew = $1 eq $word;
    }

    print if $spew;
}

__DATA__
FOO BAR: Good morning.
I want to meet you later.
JONE DOE: Good morning
FOO BAR: Thank you.
See you later.
JANE DOE: Thank you.
See you later.
```

Output:

```
FOO BAR: Good morning.
I want to meet you later.
FOO BAR: Thank you.
See you later.
```

Comment: The `[A-Z ]+` is going to match `A nice day`.  Then it's all resting on the colon alone.

Comment: @zdim And `\d` matches a single digit, but I don't see how that's relevant to this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got exactly the same output. But still I don't understand how this code extracts multiple lines. How is the flag turned on in the line without NAME: ??

Comment: It's not. The value of `$spew` only changes when something that looks like a name is found, so it just stays on (or off) and continues printing (or not) until another name is found.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: @MattJacob: There is no solution, and you shouldn't pretend that there is. Suppose `FOO BAR` says `"I have to disagree: there is no solution"`

Comment: I only meant to say (with my first comment) that it doesn't specify the condition as much as it could.  This compounds the problem @Borodin is raising, that the quesiton doesn't provide a specific enough condition to correctly parse all that may come in a transcript.

Comment: @Borodin OK, let's say that Mr. BAR says something with a colon in it. So what? The regex is anchored to the start of the line, and the subset of characters that can appear before a colon is pretty limited. Given the example input, one could reasonably assume that valid names contain only uppercase letters and spaces.

Comment: @MattJacob: If `FOO BAR` says `"I HAVE TO\nDISAGREE: there is no solution"`, what will your code make of it?

Comment: @MattJacob Consider this statement by Mr. Bar -- `FOO BAR: ... talks ...\nA GANT: we have ...` (The `GANT` happens to be an acronym used in the particular community where the conversation is taking place.  The transcriber knows nothing about our program.)  The second line, `A GANT: ...` is going to be matched as a name. This is just something I made up. An actual discussion can spring up all kinds of text.

Comment: @Borodin Oy. So let's go and downvote every single answer on SO then, because none of them accounted for the extra hypothetical conditions that weren't part of the question.

Comment: @MattJacob: It is rarely a good criterion that a piece of code satisfies the question. Far too often we see *"But it works!"* on Stack Overflow. But good code must work well in all likely circumstances, and seven lines of test data is not a useful measure. Please delete your answer, because it is misleading and destructive.

Comment: @MattJacob: Surely you realise that questions usually provide a tiny subset of the possible conditions? It is your job to write something better than `print "4\n"` when someone asks *"How do I print the sum of two numbers, say 1 and 3?"*